# How to get engagement plans that current user is enrolled in?

Tags: xdb, marketing-automation

[Sitecore Marketing Automation API](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/marketing-automation-operations-api.html) defines how to enroll a contact in a plan, but doesn't mention how to get plans that current (or specified) contact is enrolled in. Is there an API for that?
Sitecore version 9.1.

Comment: What version of Sitecore

Answer (score 2):

The plans a contact is enrolled in is stored in a built-in facet on the contact called `AutomationPlanEnrollmentCache`.

You can get the facet like this:

```
using (XConnectClient client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
{
    var contact = client.Get(
        new IdentifiedContactReference("Your Known ID Type", "Your Contact ID"),
        new ContactExpandOptions(AutomationPlanEnrollmentCache.DefaultFacetKey));
    var enrollmentCacheFacet = contact.GetFacet<AutomationPlanEnrollmentCache>(
        AutomationPlanEnrollmentCache.DefaultFacetKey);
}
```

The facet contains a list of all plans the user is enrolled in. The `AutomationPlanDefinitionId` is the ID of the plan.

[image]

I'm guessing that `ActivityId` defines which element in the plan the user is currently at, but I haven't done enough research into that to actually confirm this. The other properties on the facet should be self-explanatory :)

Answer (score 1):

In older Sitecore versions this code used to work:

```
AutomationStateManager manager = Tracker.Current.Session.CreateAutomationStateManager();
var plans = manager.GetAutomationStates().Select(s => s.PlanItem);
```

I'm not sure if it still work in the latest but it should be a good place to start.